# Convert 'double' to 'Date' in Powershell Select-Object

Tags: sql-server, powershell, type-conversion

```
 Select-Object -Property Distributor,'File Date','Report Date',Country,'Customer Name)
```

I am using above **Select-Object** command to select data from an excel sheet. The third column **'Report Date'** is throwing below error when i try to write the excel to SQL Server using **Write-SQLTableData**

```
The given value of type double from the data source cannot be converted to type data of the specified data column.
```

How may I apply format/convert in Select-Object command?

Comment: How is your date formatted? What is the value of report Date?

Comment: Without showing that `double` value, you could try converting with `$date = [datetime]::FromOADate($theDouble)`

Comment: @guiwhatsthat in Excel it is like 16.02.2021

Comment: `16.02.2021` is what Excel _displays_, but the underlying **value** you are getting in `'Report Date'` apparently is a `[double]` as the error message shows. Please answer @guiwhatsthat s question so we can see what Report Date actually contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example how you can do whatever you want with an value of a property:

```
$ScriptBlock = {$_.'Report Date'} # Do your conversion here
$psobject | Select-Object -Property Distributor,'File Date', @{n="Report Date";e=$ScriptBlock}
```

Currently the script block only selects your property, but you can convert it there, the conversion depends on the value of your property

Comment: Thanks.... It worked like below for me..
@{l='Report Date';e={If ($_.'Report Date' -as [datetime]){$_.'Report Date'} else {[DBNULL]::Value}}}